# I am able to use more memory than I allocated using malloc. Why is this happening?

Tags: c, malloc

As you can see I have allocated only 1 byte using malloc but if I want to store more than one integer I am available to do that.

```
int main()
{

  int *p=(int *)malloc(2);

    

  *p=2;
  *(p+1)=3;
  *(p+2)=4;

  printf("%d:",p);
  printf("%d\n",*p);

  printf("%d:",(p+1));
  printf("%d\n",*(p+1));

  printf("%d:",p+2);
  printf("%d\n",*(p+2));
  
  return 0;

}
```

Output-

207152:2

207156:3

207160:4

Comment: You can't really allocate one byte: you probably get a full page. That doesn't mean your program will always work because accessing memory you have not allocated is undefined behavior and we all know how much SO loves undefined behavior.

Comment: Writing beyond the bounds of allocated memory invokes undefined behavior.  Your are corrupting your runtime environment, and anything can happen.  C does not have runtime checks that some languages have. You have sole responsibility for managing your memory accesses.

Comment: Lookup [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). *Undefined behavior* means anything can happen, including the appearance that it "works".

Comment: If one need a language to keep   from doing things one should not, do not use C.

Comment: "As you can see I have allocated only 1 byte using malloc" and `malloc(2)` do not agree.